# Parse optional arguments in next function in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm starting with learning Clojure and I'm not sure how to parse an optional amount of params to next function.

Here's my code

```
(defn query
  [query & [params]]
  (jdbc/with-db-connection [db-con pg]
    (jdbc/query pg [query params])))
```

I would like to parse for example

```
(query "select * from blogs where tag=? and title=?" "blue" "foo bar")
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parse"?

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just have an extra pair of square brackets. The "&" syntax automatically puts all extra arguments into a vector, so if you do

```
(defn query
  [query-string & params]
  (jdbc/with-db-connection [db-con pg]
    (jdbc/query pg [query-string params])))
```

and then call it with

```
(query "select * from blogs where tag=? and title=?" "blue" "foo bar")
```

your `params` will contain ["blue" "foo bar"].

EDIT: you also have to watch your symbol names: if your function is named "query" you don't want to have an argument named "query" as well, or things will get confusing. I changed the argument to `query-string` instead of `query`.

Comment: `& params` puts them in a sequence and not a vector. In your example, `params` would contain `("blue", "foo bar")`

Comment: thanks for the help so far. using this  `(defn query
    [query-string & params] 
    (jdbc/with-db-connection [db-con pg]
              (jdbc/query pg [query-string params]))) ` I still get `select name, viq_id from entities where viq_id=? and name ~* ?("Bla" "fattoria")` which is "one argument" for the pg function

Comment: Frank C. -- You're right, I was looking at the square brackets in the original code and typed vector instead of sequence. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I solved my problem.

As I'm new to clojure, I was wrongly seeing that I wanted to parse multiple arguments to the `jdbc/query` function. Instead, I wanted to always parse one argument, a vector, which either contains only an sql, an sql and params, or an sql with multiple params.

This is how I solved it.

```
(defn query
([query-string] 
(jdbc/with-db-connection [db-con pg]
          (jdbc/query pg [query-string])))
([query-string & params]
 (jdbc/with-db-connection [db-con pg]
          (jdbc/query pg (concat [query-string] params)))))
```